# Sa password automatically keeps changing automatically

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Since 2-3 weeks ago, the `sa` password has been continuously changing automatically. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: what is the server environment? Are you sure someone else isn't changing it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the you have not set the SA account up to change password after a set amount of time. In PCI compliance mode you may have to roll security passwords. However, you should account for this for your SA accounts.

Comment: Could you tell me more detail about 'set SA Account up to change password after a set amount time'. Where can I disable this one? Thanks

Comment: This is an attribute of the local user account on the server in which SSRS is running, unless you are using a domain controller. Log into the server hosting SSRS and select account management-->user account. Make sure the password never expires is set to true.

Answer (score -2):

```
**SA passwords** don't change or reset automatically.
```

You can visit possible solution at this link: 
[sa password keep changing automatically](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1007864-sa-password-keep-changing-automatically)